# View goes up when hiding navigation bar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

My View goes up when using this line of code

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: yes it will go up if you hide navigation bar in that u can change the frame u can bring it where you want

Answer (score 0):

`[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];`

Answer (score 0):

May be you have given navigation height to view in the frame.

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0,height of navigation bar,320,480);
```

Answer (score 0):

How you can do is you can change the frame of view after hiding the navigation bar if you set y axis position 50 it will won change

```
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,480);
```

and this will set your view in same position and even you can change the axis based on device